# Show all Dropbox conflicted copies

Tags: macos, dropbox

I'd like some way to see all the conflicted copies from my Dropbox folder.

I personally use a Mac mostly, but I welcome Windows and Linux solutions.

Comment: you want a script which lists them?

Comment: @Sathya Yes: a script, 'Smart Folder' (Mac), freeware app, anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I couldn't find a good way to do this for Mac, I wrote my own script using the `find` command and some AppleScript.

Paste this into AppleScript editor and save it as an app:

```
set conflictedFiles to do shell script "cd ~/Dropbox; find -L . \\( -path \"*.dropbox*\" -prune \\) -o \\( -name \"*conflicted*\" -print \\)"
set fileList to paragraphs of conflictedFiles as list
repeat with currFile in fileList
  set currPath to (path to home folder as string) & "Dropbox" & POSIX file (characters 3 thru -1 of (currFile as string) as string)
  tell application "Finder" to make new Finder window to currPath
end repeat
```

**This script finds all the conflicted files and opens a Finder window to each one.**
Be careful using this if you think you've got a lot of conflicts; your desktop may get covered with windows!

Note that this will still work fine if you've got symlinks in your Dropbox folder.

Answer (score 2):

MacPaw's Gemini duplicate file utility can also route out these and file copies of all kinds. Then you can delete them easily. It's $6.99 in the App store. Just zapped about 500 conflicted docs.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear, if you want a listing of all files which are conflicted in Windows command prompt cd to the Dropbox folder and type in

```
dir *"Selective Sync"* /s /b
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a script in `sh` which does this. It ought to run on any standard Linux or Unix shell - and also supports piping filenames through `encfsctl` if you have an `encfs`-encrypted folder in there.

You can find it [on github](https://github.com/andrewf23/misc-scripts/blob/master/show-dropbox-conflicts).